# WP 4.0 - Image placements in posts (place by margins, pixels, admin GUI)

Tags: css, wordpress, image, user-interface, admin

Since I upgraded my wordpress installation to 4.0 (from an old 3.x version) the option to place images in posts/pages (in admin/backend-mode) by pixels disappearded? (margin-left/right/top/bottom) I want to place images individually (not by classes) instead by inline styling.

Is there a way to do that in the new version, or is there any good plugin which solved this problem for me that you know about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be done by this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-image-styles/